# Using SSL for iOS string from URL request

Tags: ios, ssl, web, nsstring, request

If I use `stringWithContentsOfURL` to get data from a web server that uses SSL (address begins with https://) will it work and use SSL for the request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work.

Note that you shouldn't use stringWithContentsOfURL from the main thread, though, because it may not return for a long time and your application can be terminated by the system for being unresponsive.

Comment: So its the NSURL object thats doing the work, you can use canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate methods from NSURLConnection to obtain certificate information.